# Comment notification for user that offered bounty

Tags: discussion, comments, bounty

Does a user that offered a bounty for someone else's question get notified when comments are posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not unless they would have gotten a notification without having bountied the question.  (I.e. from an @ reply, by also being the post author, etc.)